# Is it possible to customize android's camera crop intent view?

Tags: android, camera

Is it possible to customize android's camera crop intent view ? How to create a custom view like the image in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817236/how-do-you-make-a-resizable-rectangle-for-cropping-images-in-android)?

Thanks

Comment: custom view like this? link is missing

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585341/android-camera-intent-with-crop

Comment: No.I did not want to show camera crop intent view.I want to just crop the image.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
```

Comment: Do you know how to create a view like the image in the given link?